# Custom Label Translations in Lightning Controller not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a few cases where I wish to translate labels in lightning controllers and I can't get it to work.

For instance, the label head in a lightning:datatable won't work with `$A.get("!$Label.c.Model"),` - it'll just leave the column header blank. Worth mentioning is that these fields are translated in in regular Salesforce correctly, is it possible to set the `label` down below to what `fieldName` is referencing? `Model__c` in this case.

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.mycolumns', [
        {type: "button", typeAttributes: {
            label: '',
            iconName: 'utility:add',
            name: 'selectRecord',
            title: 'selectRecord',
            disabled: false,
            value: 'edit',
            variant: {fieldName: 'variantValue'},
        }},
        {label: 'Model', fieldName: 'Model__c', type: 'text', sortable: true},

            ]);
    },
```

Also, inside $A.createComponents - it works to use labels in the function call (as specified below), but not on the actual lightning button label - it'll also, like above, just leave a blank button.

```
handleShowModal: function(component, event, helper) {
    var myAccount = component.get("v.theAccountName")
    var modalBody;
    $A.createComponents([
        ["c:ModalContent", {
            "accountName": myAccount,
            }],
        ["lightning:button",{
            "label": $A.get("!$Label.c.Booking_Confirmation"),
            "variant": "brand",
            "class": "slds-align_absolute-center",
            "onclick": component.getReference("c.fireEvent")
            }],
    ],
   function(content, status) {
       if (status === "SUCCESS") {
           modalBody = content;
           component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
               header: $A.get("!$Label.c.Booking_Confirmation"),
               body: modalBody,
               showCloseButton: true,
               cssClass: "mymodal",

           })
       }
   });
},
```

Any particular reason why?

TL;DR: What do I need to do to have custom labels working in lightning:datatables and $A.createComponents.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
$A.get("$Label.c.Model")
```

i.e. no `!` in the string.

The `!` is part of the expression delimiter `{!` in the component.

Comment: Awesome, that solves the button thing, thanks a lot! Is there a way to have the column headers just reference the fieldName, or would I need to create a custom label for each header as well? I kinda want the header to be exactly what fieldName is

Comment: @erikvm At present you have to build your own code to get hold of the describe data that includes field labels that you could use as column headers which is a fair bit of work. Using labels as you suggest will work too.

Comment: Thanks Keith, one final thing, do you know how to handle custom labels inside aura attributes. I've got a default list that looks like this:

<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
                                                        {'label': 'Phone', 'value': 'option1'},
                                                        {'label': 'Email', 'value': 'option2'},
                                                        ]"/>

However, I'm getting an error if I simply try to go "{!$Label.c.Phone}" in the label in the phone field. Any potential solution?

Comment: @erikvm I think you'll have to build the data in an init handler; I'm not 100% sure but get the impression that the `default` only supports constant data not expressions.